# How do I enumerate whether a connector is established in an Azure Logic App via PowerShell?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm interested in using a Logic App to do something in AzureAD when triggered. It appears that the AzureAD action uses Azure [Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/apis-list), which I have established an account for, but how do I view if a logic app is using a connector via PowerShell?

Screen shot of the logic app and what I'm trying to gather via PS https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dm9gm.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to some test, we can not get the AD authentication account by powershell. If we use `Get-AzureRmLogicApp` or `Get-AzureRmLogicAppRunAction`(or `Get-AzLogicApp`, `Get-AzLogicAppRunAction`), it will not show any information about your AD account. The AD account stored in the API connection which exists in the same resource group of your logic app(the name is like `azuread`).

[image]

[image]

Your ad authentication account shows in the `Display name` of the API connection, so try to use `Get-AzureRmResource` or `Get-AzResource` to get the API connection.

[image]

But there are limited fields return in the result of the command. So I think currently we can't get the result you expected by powershell. You can raise a post on this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback) page to suggest azure team to add a feature about it.